# Showing pdf file from database with php

Tags: php, html

I've been using this code to show my images

```
        <dd><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

But when I want to show an pdf file I get nothing on my page, i only get my the frame from the iframe tag.

I've using this code to show my pdf file (also stored as a blob):

```
        <dt> <?php echo '<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"</iframe>'; ?></dt>
```

Comment: your iframe `src` attribute missing opening double quote "

Comment: thanks, now I can see some pdf looking page, but still can't see or open the file.

Comment: which browser and version are you using? @Frederic

Comment: firefox 56.0 @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Frederic well, after seeing your comment above, this to me suggests that a recent upgrade may have changed your default settings of "showing the file/pdf" to a force open. check your browser settings, I've my money on that but I could be wrong. It's a possibility.

Comment: I changed the settings to download the pdf file, but when I open it says the file is damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possible reasons why you have the problem:

1. The data in the database is corrupt
2. The retrieval of the data from the database leads to corrupted data
3. The HTML you created simply doesn't work in your browser.

To find out the culprit, you can do the following steps:

- Retrieve the PDF-data from the database manually and try to open it in a PDF-reader. If that doesn't work, your PDF-data in the table is most likely corrupt. Check the process saving the data to the database.
- Encode the retrieved data to base64 (check if that was done correctly by decoding it again and open the decoded data in the reader).
- Output the base64 encoded text from you PHP-script and compare the two base64-blocks for equality. If they differ, your script seems to corrupt the data when retrieving the data from the DB.
- Create a static HTML-page, using the base64-data you generated before and open it in a browser. If that doesn't work, your HTML is not correct for embedding PDF into it or the browser simply doesn't support showing PDF embedded.

Comment: I started by looking at the file in my database, however when I download it, it becomes .bin and I can't figure out how to open this. 
But this goes for the images as well which are working fine on the website.

Comment: Just rename it to .pdf or call your reader from the command line specifying the filename explicitly. The HTML-code for embedded images differ from embedded PDFs. One is the image-tag, the other uses iframe. Their might be differences in the way a browser handles the src-attribute in each of them.

Comment: when I rename to .pdf and try to open, it says the file is damaged.

Comment: So there you go. You might check if your way of retrieving the data from the DB manually was correct by trying the same with some image-data (if that shows up in your image viewer, it's the data in the DB, not your download-process)

Comment: I just tried with an image, and I can't open that as well when I download it manually from my database, but it will work in my site with the code above, so maybe im doing the manually retrieving wrong? 

I go into my database and I click on the [blob - 64 KIB) and I get a download.

Comment: Instead of using your database client you might just add code to your PHP-page saving the retrieved data to a file you can use for that test. If it comes up corrupted as well, it might be corrupt data in the database or corrupting data due to your code retrieving it from the DB, though. But better that than nothing.

Comment: I been sparring around with the switching the images and pdfs. And I think the problem must be there is something wrong with my retrieving code when it comes to pdf.

Comment: Glad I could help (by pointing you to a way to track things down). You might accept my answer for this if you want, removing your question from the list of unsolved cases. If you tracked down the problem in more detail, you can open a new question that contains these allowing specific answers to it.

Comment: I still havent figured it out, but you defiantly pointed me in the right direction. Appreciate it!